# NPM Tokens: Apply only to Specific Packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, authorization, acl

I have an NPM Account.  This account owns a number of individual packages.  It's also listed as a maintainer on a number of accounts.

I want to create an authentication token that will let me publish my individually owned packages, but NOT to the ones I'm a maintainer of.

Does NPM's permission system allow for this level of control?  Or will tokens always apply to every package you own or are a maintainer of?

Does this change if you're using NPM's enterprise product?

Is there a place I can find this information for myself? The [NPM docs I found](https://docs.npmjs.com/integrations/integrating-npm-with-external-services), while useful, didn't cover the permission model in great detail.